# class variable keeps getting reset

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, client

So, I have a thread class that isn't public since it's put in with the server class. I have a `clientSocket` class that interacts with the `clientWindow` class. the `clientWindow` class takes input and sends it to the server. There is no connection issue. the `clientWindow` class passes the String to the server by calling a method (`getString(String s)`) that sets a variable (`clientIn`) to that string `s`. I have it so that the method inside of the thread class syso's a message saying: `"clientIn was set by the client. " + clientIn"`. Keep in mind that `clientIn` is public and static. When the run method for the thread class is executed, it runs the following code:

```
ClientWindow cw = new ClientWindow();
int maxClientsCount = this.maxClientsCount;

//maxClientsCount is just 15.

clientThread[] threads = this.threads;
try {
    /*
     * Create input and output streams for this client.
     */
    is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

    //getting the player's name. (unincluded code)

    os.println("Welcome " + name);

    //sets the clientname to the name of the client which is stored in 
    //threads.(unincluded code)

    //this for loop sends the message to all clients.
    for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
        if (threads[i] != null) {
            threads[i].os.println("new user " + name + " entered");
        }
    }

    //waits until there are at least 2 players connected until the game can 
    //start (unincluded code)

    ZombieDiceServer.waitStart();
```

that method just makes it so that the start button enables and a while loop waits until the admin presses that button to start the game. players may still connect during this time period.

```
//(unincluded game code)

synchronized (this) {
    String restart = "";
    System.out.println("clientIn: " + clientIn);
    while (true) {
        restart = clientIn;
        if (!clientIn.isEmpty()) {
            //the following for loop prints out the given string to all 
            //threads/clients.
            for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
                if (threads[i] != null) {
                    threads[i].os.println("<" + name + "> " + clientIn);
                }
            }
        }
        //(unnecessary code)
    }
}
```

The `getString(String s)` method is below:

```
public static void getString(String s) {
    clientIn = s;
    System.out.println("clientIn was set by the client. " + clientIn);
}
```

`ClientSocket` console output:

```
responseLine: Enter your name.
responseLine: *** A new user M entered the chat room !!! ***
responseLine: Welcome B to Zombie Dice.
clientIn was set by the client. B
responseLine: To leave, enter "/quit" in a new line.
responseLine: Please wait while other players join!
responseLine: *** A new user B entered the chat room !!! ***
clientIn was set by the client. hi
```

`ZombieDiceServer` console output:

```
clientIn was called. 
clientIn at start: 
clientIn was called. 
clientIn at start: 
clientIn: 
clientIn:
```

**notice that the client that called the method in the thread remembers it, but not the thread that it was sent to.** Why?!

Comment: "by calling a method (getString(String s)) that sets a variable (clientIn) to that string s". Good method naming!

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope don't know if that was sarcasm but I'll take it as a compliment, thanks!

Comment: Can you give us the declaration of clientIn? It's difficult for me to understand your architecture, I think you should rethink it so that thread send messages to each other instead of manipulating a global static variable. But you may be able to fix your issue only with the volatile keyword.

Comment: @Th1sguy26 it was sarcasm, since you are setting the value of a variable, the typical naming convention would be to call the method setString(String s) when you are setting the variable and getString() would return the clientIn

Comment: @Th1sguy26 getSomething methods should never change the state of an object or anything, never ever, unless you intentionally want to troll everyone that will try to read your code. Sorry for the sarcasm, this reminded me of too many horrible debugging sessions.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope i said in there that it was public static. Is that what you mean by the declaration? Also, I thought that was what I was doing. Once the getString() method is called it sets clientIn to s and therefore i should be able to send it to all the threads but for some reason it is not remembering the String or it's getting reset somewhere.

Comment: Thread don't always see modifications on variables that happen outside of their own thread if those variable are not marked as volatile, this is because of complex JVM optimizations. If you have the courage you can read this to understand why: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr133.pdf. So if the declaration is "public static String ...", you can try "public static volatile String ..." and see if it helps solve your problem.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope my bad, I’ll make not of that next time, thank you for the constructive criticism.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope no problem, I’ll get right to it

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope which section would you like for me to read? Can’t see anything about volatile.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope still there?

Comment: You can't read a specific section, you should read all of it, but if you don't have the time now it's fine just add volatile to your variable knowing that it cover cases where multiple threads need to access the same variable.